# How to create a list compose from names of a predicate in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

How to create a list compose from names of a predicate 
example:
**name(a), name(b), name(c), name(d)**

I want to achieve a list like L=[a,b,c,d].

Please help me someone with code or some advice.

Comment: add the code you have already created

Comment: Consider going over the documentation or general links. such as [link](https://www.swi-prolog.org/Links.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findall/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) builds a list for you, if the predicate name and arity is known just use it to get the list L

```
?- findall(X,name(X),L).
```

If the predicate name is unknown, you can use [`call/N`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2) where `N` is the arity of the predicate plus one. For instance:

```erlang
?- [user].
|: a_name(a).
|: a_name(b).
|: a_name(c).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 3 clauses
true.

?- Name =a_name,findall(X,call(Name,X),L).
Name = a_name,
L = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: Actually, _functor_ is a _name_ plus an _arity_. E.g. `findall/3` is a functor: `findall` is the _functor name_ and `3` is the _functor arity_.

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks, I'll report your fix. I tought `findall/3` is a *predicate indicator*.

Comment: Is both. A predicate indicator is also a functor but a functor is not necessarily a predicate indicator.